# Merging UITableViewCells

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I would like to be able to drag a cell over another cell, and when I release it would effectively "merge" the cells (display a different cell).  I'm not sure if a `UITableView` is the best control or a `UICollectionView`.  Does anyone have any thoughts on how to proceed?

Comment: means, you want to marge two cell in one. right?

Comment: That is correct.  I would like to "lift" the existing cell off of the UITableView, move it over an existing cell (providing an indication which cell), and then drop the cell which effectively merges it.  The underlying collection is a bag of "merged models" and "standalone models".

Comment: Got it done!  It wasn't as bad as I thought it would be.

Comment: @user833999 - Please share your solution. This topic comes up pretty high in Google Search and is worthless as is because the solution isn't here.

Comment: @user833999 I give you 50 Rep if you share your solution (and if there is no better one ;-)

Comment: @user833999 WHY AREN'T YOU SHARING????? Please share! I have a similar problem!!!

Comment: If I ever get the time, I may open up a GitHub account and post my solution as a reusable control.  I think there's a pattern here that can be fairly generic.  The variables would likely be the animations.

Comment: @user833999 Please post this as an answer, don't add it to the question. I can't award bounties to questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here's the solution I used to develop it in pseudocode.**

1. Add a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to the UITableView
2. On the `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`, use the `[UITableView indexPathForRowAtPoint]` in order to determine what cell is being "long pressed".  You will turn this cell into the **hover** `UITableViewCell`.
3. Set a reference variable to the corresponding model object.
4. Use the `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` to render an image of the actual UITableViewCell contents. Create a `UIImageView` and add some custom chrome to it (shadows, etc.)
5. Add the custom UIImageView as a subview to the UITableView, and remove the original selected **pinned** UITableViewCell (removeFromSuperview).
6. On `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged`, calculate the location of the **hover** `UITableViewCell` in the `UITableView` and animate the **pinned** cell. (You will also want to toggle the animation for the previously highlighted **pinned** cell).
7. When the user releases the LongPress, you'll want to re-order the model array, remove the underlying **pinned** cell, and then reload the `UITableView` all in a `beginUpdates` call.

There are a few other things to watch out for such as scrolling when you hit a boundary condition, dropping the hover cell over the original location, etc. but that's the basic gist of it.  Hopefully that helps.

Comment: do you have some sample code for this? I am trying to do the same thing but haven't had much luck.

Answer (score 4):

May be I didn't get u properly but as I got, u want to merge cells by dragging so implement some code for you.Have a look at this.

If u Wanna something like this...

[image: Screenshot]

use editing code like that :---

ViewDidLoad initializing array and set table to edit mode as:

```
fruitsArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Apple",@"Banana",@"Mango",@"Guava",@"PineApple",@"Watermelon",@"Grapes",@"GroundNut",@"Muskmelon",@"Orange",@"Cherry",nil];
[tblView setEditing:YES];
```

datasources for tableView set as:->

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
    if (sourceIndexPath.row!=destinationIndexPath.row) {
        NSString *sourceString=[fruitsArray objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
        NSString *destinationString=[fruitsArray objectAtIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];

        destinationString=[destinationString stringByAppendingFormat:@",%@",sourceString];

        [fruitsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:destinationIndexPath.row withObject:destinationString];
        [fruitsArray removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];

        [tblView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Try this [sampleCode](http://ge.tt/9EzHTVm/v/0)

Comment: Why don't you use `!=` operator at `moveRowAtIndexPath` `if` ?

Comment: That's kinda the easy part of the problem, doing a nice transition to merge the cells will be the difficult thing.

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to animate the height of the cell you're keeping by changing it in the `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: thnks @A-Live I just forgot to insert !=

Comment: Good idea. Unfortunately this kills reordering.

Answer (score 1):

I used Long press gesture for this. here is sample code

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    {

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:cell action:nil];
                longPress.delegate = self;
                [cell addGestureRecognizer:longPress];

    }

    - (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
        if([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]]){
            [gestureRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(moveRight:)];
        }
        return YES;

        if([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]){
            [gestureRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(tapAction:)];
        }
        return YES;
    }

    - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
        return YES;
    }


- (void)moveRight:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {

   /*if (sender.view.tag==4)
    {
        [super setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        [self.Table4 setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        */

    UIView *view = sender.view;

    int t = sender.view.tag;
     CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:view.superview];

    NSLog(@"its added %f", point.x);
    NSLog(@"its added %f", point.y);
   // view.frame = CGRectMake(sender.view.frame.origin.x, sender.view.frame.origin.y+200,200, 30);
    CGPoint center = view.center;
    center.x = point.x ;
    center.y = point.y ;
    view.center = center;
    [self.view addSubview:view];



  //  int x = Table4.frame.origin.x;
   // int y = Table4.frame.origin.y;

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        CGPoint center = view.center;
        center.x += point.x - _priorPoint.x;
        center.y += point.y - _priorPoint.y;

       NSLog(@"its Center %f", center.x);


        if (center.x > Table4.frame.origin.x  && 
            center.x < Table4.frame.origin.x  + 
            Table4.frame.size.width &&
            center.y > Table4.frame.origin.y  && 
            center.y < Table4.frame.origin.y  + 
            Table4.frame.size.height
            ) 
        {
            int count = [self.rowdata count];

            if (t>=100 && t<200)
            {
                t=t-100;
                 [self.rowdata insertObject:[listData objectAtIndex:t] atIndex:count];
            }
            else if (t>=200 && t<300)
            {
                 t=t-200;
                 [self.rowdata insertObject:[listData2 objectAtIndex:t] atIndex:count];
            }
            else
            {
                  t=t-300;
                 [self.rowdata insertObject:[listData3 objectAtIndex:t] atIndex:count];
            }           

            //[self.rowdata addObject:[listData objectAtIndex:t]];
            //[sender release];
            [Table4 reloadData];
            [Table1 reloadData];
            [Table2 reloadData];
            [Table3 reloadData];
        }

        view.center = center;
    //}


        _priorPoint = point;
    }
}
```

I think this is helpful for you. Take some code what you want from this.